# Issues running OSMnx on conda

Tags: python, conda, osmnx

I'm trying to get the Python package OSMnx running on my Windows10 machine. I'm still new to python so struggling with the basics.
I've followed the instructions here https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ and have successfully created a new conda environment for it to run in. The installation seems to have gone ok.
However, as soon as I try and import it, I get the following error

```
>>> import osmnx as ox
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\.conda\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\osmnx\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ._api import *
  File "C:\Users\User\.conda\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\osmnx\_api.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .distance import get_nearest_edge
  File "C:\Users\User\.conda\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\osmnx\distance.py", line 5, in <module>
    import networkx as nx
  File "C:\Users\User\.conda\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\networkx\__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
    import networkx.generators
  File "C:\Users\User\.conda\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\networkx\generators\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from networkx.generators.intersection import *
  File "C:\Users\User\.conda\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\networkx\generators\intersection.py", line 13, in <module>
    from networkx.algorithms import bipartite
  File "C:\Users\User\.conda\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\networkx\algorithms\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from networkx.algorithms.dag import *
  File "C:\Users\User\.conda\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\networkx\algorithms\dag.py", line 23, in <module>
    from fractions import gcd
ImportError: cannot import name 'gcd' from 'fractions' (C:\Users\User\.conda\envs\ox\lib\fractions.py)
```

I'm running with

```
   conda version : 4.8.2
   conda-build version : 3.18.11
   python version : 3.7.6.final.0
```

Is anyone able to advise me? Sorry if this is obvious, as I said I'm new to all this. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module [`fractions`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/fractions.html) is part of the Python standard library. There [used to be a function `gcd`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/fractions.html#fractions.gcd), which, as the linked documentation says, is:

> Deprecated since version 3.5: Use `math.gcd()` instead.

Since the function `gcd` was removed from the module `fractions` in Python 3.9, it seems that the question uses Python 3.9, not Python 3.7.6 as the question notes, because that Python version [still had `fractions.gcd`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/fractions.html#fractions.gcd).

The error is raised by `networkx`. Upgrading to the latest version of `networkx` is expected to avoid this issue:

```
pip install -U networkx
```

Indeed, the change that avoids this error from `networkx` is: https://github.com/networkx/networkx/commit/b007158f3bfbcf77c52e4b39a81061914788ddf9#diff-21e03bb1d46583650bcad6e960f2ab8a5397395c986942b59314033e963dd3fcL23, and has been released as part of `networkx==2.4`, `networkx==2.5`, and `networkx==2.5.1`, as the tags listed on the commit's GitHub page inform. The current line in `networkx` is: https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/d70b314b37168f0ea7c5b0d7f9ff61d73232747b/networkx/algorithms/dag.py#L9, i.e., `from math import gcd`.

Comment: Brilliant. Yes that seems to have been exactly the problem I was having. I took the Python version from conda info but you're right, when I queried python itself, it seems I am running version 3.9.2. I have used conda to update networkx and the errors have disappeared when I now import osmnx. Thank you so much. Learning how to deal with all the packages and environments in Python is not easy.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem. I installed all my packages using conda-forge (recommended install for OSMnx - https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Conda-forge does not support package updates, if I understand correctly. Instead, remove networkx and reinstall, but be sure to specify version. You will need to reinstall osmnx too

```
conda remove -c conda-forge networkx
conda install -c conda-forge networkx=2.5
conda install -c conda-forge osmnx
```